# Meta Information in FrontEnd Magento

Tags: php, magento, seo

I want to add the Meta information in my custom module, I did add the tab and form in AdminPanel which contains the fields

1. Meta title,
2. Meta Description
3. Meta Keywords

   and writes the data in the database,I want to add this meta information in frontend products page, I don't understand how it is used in front end with products, Any Help will be appreciated Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add it in Block as well as in your controller also

**For Block**

Add this function in your custom block

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
    {     
        $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($head) {
            $head->setTitle("Your title");
            $head->setKeywords("Your meta keywords");
            $head->setDescription("Your meta description");
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

And **For controller** you can add like

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Manufacturer');
```

hope this will sure help you

Comment: fetch from collection or model and set variable in controller or block

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller (save form action);

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($title)->setDescription($description)->setKeywords($keywords);
```